# what approach to use to save a variable beyond lifetime of app

Tags: ios, ios8

I have a small number of variables which I want to save, which needs to survive the app being killed and restarted.
Is NSUserDefaults the best approach to store this data?
Any other approach I should consider?

The other thing to consider is that the data is created through interaction with a Today extension widget.

thanks

Comment: What is the data?  If it's configuration then `NSUserDefaults` is the way forward, else something like writing a `.plist` from a dictionary into the documents/application support/caches directory would work.

Comment: it's user generated data (e.g. a timestamp), not configuration. Sounds like the plist is more correct. i'll give it a go, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you have and how many. If there is few properties that won't change in time and it is not complex and you wouldn't do any heavy calculation on it, the NSUserDefaults if right for you.

But if any of above statement is not right you might be wanting to look at Core Data. It needs more work and learning then NSUserDefault but can be worth it in the end.